# "is being" vs "of"

Tags: grammar

Can you please explain me which sentence is grammatically correct ? This sentence is from a chronology. I am describing an event in my sentence

```
23 October 2013 - the soil material is being rejected for dumping.
```

or

```
23 October 2013 - the soil material's rejection for dumping.
```

Comment: This is not directly related to the question, but I wonder whether the material was rejected so that it would be dumped somewhere soon or the material was rejected because it wasn't good enough to be used for dumping (which was the main purpose, like landfill, maybe?).

Comment: The first is a sentence; the second is not (it's a Noun Phrase). As this is a past event, you might use past tense "was rejected".  But if there are many entries in the chronology, you might just take out "is", leaving the clipped, partial sentence style "Soil rejected for dumping"

Answer (score 1):

*Is being* is a continuous tense.  Continuous present tenses are used to emphasize something is happening *now*, but also to say that a (typically involved or significant) process to do something is now happening.

> 23 October 2013 - the soil material is being rejected for dumping.

This sounds like some process had been set in motion that, when completed, resulted in the soil material being rejected for dumping.  I would assume that since you mentioned in this manner, you expected that process to complete successfully.

> 23 October 2013 - the soil material's rejection for dumping.

There's no verb in this sentence, unless you mean *material's* to say *material is*, which doesn't make sense since soil cannot be a "rejection."

So add a verb:

> 23 October 2013 - the soil material dumping was rejected

Answer (score 0):

Your first option (present continuous) is a grammatically correct sentence, but it is not what would be most often used for an event in a chronology. It might be used if it was used to introduce another simultaneous event, such as:

> The soil material is being rejected for dumping. Everyone is getting frustrated.

or if it is an event that is repeated or ongoing:

> The soil material is being rejected for dumping, time and time again.

Your second option (noun phrase) is a grammatically correct noun phrase, but it is not a sentence, and not at all how someone would describe this event in a chronology. (Unless it was the title of a section?)

In a chronology, you'd be more likely to see the simple present tense:

> The soil material is rejected for dumping

or the past tense:

> The soil material was rejected for dumping

or, with "the" and "be" elided:

> soil material rejected for dumping

You should choose either present or past tense for your whole chronology, and stick to it.

The last option I presented, with "the" and "be" elided, isn't a full, grammatically correct sentence, but I believe it's the most common way to write these things.